# os.path.isFile(file) throwing error in Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, os.path

Since my code is so simple, I will include it in its entirety:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os.path
def main(argv):
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "insuficient arguments. Use like: lichcrypt <d/e> </path/to/file>"
    else:
        operation = argv[1]
        filepath = argv[2]
        print operation
        print os.path.isFile(filepath)
main(sys.argv)
```

The error, when run script-style from cmd line is:

```
liam@liam-GA-970A-UD3:~$ lichcrypt.py something not/a/file/path
something
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/liam/bin/lichcrypt.py", line 12, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "/home/liam/bin/lichcrypt.py", line 11, in main
    print os.path.isFile(filepath)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'isFile'
```

Now, this code is obviously very useless. Eventually it will encrypt files, but untill I can get my hands on the file itself it can't do anything.

Any thoughts on why os.filepath.isFile() does not seem to exist anymore?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile

Comment: The name of the function is: `os.path.isfile`. Lowercase `f`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @AjayBrahmakshatriya. As stated in my title however, I am running Python 2.7. I am aware of the Python docs, which would seem to be in contradiction to my results.

Comment: You can use dir(os.path) to see all the functions defined in the module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function names in python are case sensitive, the function is `isfile` not `isFile` .

reference link : [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os.path
def main(argv):
    if len(sys.argv) < 3:
        print "insuficient arguments. Use like: lichcrypt <d/e> </path/to/file>"
    else:
        operation = argv[1]
        filepath = argv[2]
        print operation
        print os.path.isfile(filepath)
main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: Oh goodness. A simple case error? My apologies, and my thanks.

Comment: Is the deletion of such a silly question encouraged or discouraged? I see I have already garnered myself one down-vote.

Comment: @Sir.Lich people get it into this kind of problems. This question is clear and concise no need to delete.